# VBS Stop option forced to kill on 1 sec :(

Tags: vbscript

I was writing a vbs script to monitor a process and restart it if it died.

however as i was new to vbs i made a mistake in identifying the running process and had a infinate loop of starting a new version and hence crashed my pc....

i have fixed the code to work properly now but in the script properties>script tab the "stop script after specified number of seconds" has been set to 1 and if i disable this option and kick apply.. its still set :(  this has only started being like this after i opened a billion cmd consoles and crashed my pc.... is this some sort of security feature.. how do i disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had exactly the same problem on W7 Ultimate.

The following article was helpful:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wsh_setindivprops.mspx?mfr=true

"To set global properties for all scripts that are run with the Windows-based script host
1. Click Start, and then click Run.

1. In the Open box, enter wscript, and then click OK. The Windows Script Host Settings dialog box appears.
2. Select the Stop script after specified number of seconds check box.
3. In the seconds box, enter the time limit you want to place on all scripts. 
   "

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the [scriptname].wsh file in the same directory as the script. Possibly that's been made read-only or similar?

That's the file that contains the settings. You can find more details in this MSDN article: [Setting and Customizing Script Properties (.wsh)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8fe3wt9%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Edit: Some new suggestions that might help:

Try going to this key in the registry: `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings` and checking if there is a setting in there that might be the reason. Might be worth going to the same path but under `Current User` as well (so `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings`).

Otherwise there is an option in the Group Policy Editor called [Maximum wait time for Group Policy scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938768.aspx). I don't think this would affect you but might be worth making sure.

Finally, if neither of the above suggestions help maybe either of the following might at least alleviate the problem:
There is a property called `WScript.Timeout` which you can set at the beginning of your scripts (like `WScript.Timeout = 60`) that might help.
There is also a command line parameter `\T` to `wscript` that can be used to setting the timeout as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xazzc41b%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: there is no .wsh file, yes hidden files are shown. i can create a wshfile if i try change the option to not kill,, but it still kills even when i run the wsh file

Comment: @Arthur: maybe the .wsh file is stored somewhere else but is still linking to your script via the `path`. Try doing a search for `*.wsh`.

Comment: only past ones in the bin  :( it would seam the default is to kill it on my machine and not to kill on others. i can get it to run properly if i run the wsh from the console.. but i cant run it direct like i can on other machines.. it would appear the default has changed on my machine after i crashed it with my vbs script

Comment: @Arthus: And if you try to change the properties, no .wsh file is created? Maybe you can try to create one manually in that case and put it next to your script and see if it'll use that file instead of the default. You can see in that link what they should look like.

Comment: I would appear that I have badly explained or you have missunderstood. a .wsh file can be created and run from the cmd line it will yeild correct results, the problem is that by default the settings for a .vbs file with no accociated .wsh are not to terminate... however this has been changed on my system. i wish to reverse this change!

Comment: @Arthur: My mistake, when answering your comments I forgot your original question and just focused on the comments themselves. I'll update my question with some new suggestions.