# How to stop vbscript msgbox from autoclosing?

Tags: vbscript

I am writing vbscript that contains multiple MsgBox functions. The first MsgBox appears on the screen but it auto-closes itself and the following MsgBoxes do not appear. I think vbscript also stops executing after the first MsgBox. Is there any way I can stop it from occuring? I want to be able to close it myself. Thanks.

Edit: Figured it Out
[VBS Stop option forced to kill on 1 sec :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146308/vbs-stop-option-forced-to-kill-on-1-sec)

Comment: If you don't need a modal dialog then don't use one.  Your users will thank you.

Comment: Would likely help to see some code.

Comment: Create your own answer, and accept it. Don't let this question hangin' for years, like so many others. Please.

Answer (score 2):

The docs state clearly:

> MsgBox Function: Displays a message in a dialog box, **waits** for the
>   user to click a button, and returns a value indicating which button
>   the user clicked.

So the MsgBox should not 'auto-close'. The only way I know to (seemingly) auto-close a MsgBox is to terminate the script by using the //T parameter to set a time out.

Given:

```
Option Explicit

WScript.Echo "Will call MsgBox"
MsgBox "Waiting for the cow"
WScript.Echo "MsgBox done"
```

I get:

```
cscript autoclosemsgbox.vbs
Will call MsgBox
MsgBox done
```

when I close the MsgBox (even after a long wait), but

```
cscript //T:3 autoclosemsgbox.vbs
Will call MsgBox
Script execution time was exceeded on script "autoclosemsgbox.vbs".
Script execution was terminated.
```

(mark the missing "MsgBox done")

So

1. check if there is an timeout active (using //T:0 should override)
2. consider @stark's advice to avoid modal dialogs (perhaps looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18217682/603855) will give you an idea)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for autoclosing msgbox in help menu `Windows Script Host - Popup Method`

ie.

```
Dim WshShell, BtnCode

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

BtnCode = WshShell.Popup("Do you feel alright?", 3)
```

-- 3 "waiting seconds"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have the WScript to terminate after n-seconds of execution.

Open Run ( *Windows + R* ) or CMD. Type Wscript press enter.

Uncheck the box that says *Stop script after specified number of seconds:*

Or if you are running the script from a .WSH file you may need to edit the wsh file. Open the WSH file using a text editor and remove the `Timeout=n` under `[Options]` (n is number of seconds til termination)